# Concatenated and Minified Script, Inline vs External, for Single Page Applications in Production

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that is a Single page application. So as far as I know, all the script files are loaded at the beginning of execution and are not shared across pages (as there is only one page).

In development, using gulp tasks, I inject a `<script>` tag for each file (about 70-80 in total) so that I can debug and easily test.

But for production, I decided to use gulp-minify to concatenate and minify all of my .js files into a script.min.js file and do the same for my .css files. This way, I only have one `<script>` tag and one `<link>` tag for my code and stylesheets.

My `index.html takes the form`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.min.css">
    <script src="dist/scripts.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Body -->
  </body>

</html>
```

My question is:

Provided that this is a single page app, and these large minified files are loaded at the beginning anyway...would it make more sense to use a gulp tool to essentially insert the contents of these files into a single inline `<style>` and `<script>` tag? I have seen this on websites such as Gmail when you click view source. Perhaps this is to hide their implementation, but I was just curious, would this positively or negatively impact site performance? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

NOTE: I know these are only two files, so the overhead for 2 HTTP requests probably is not that great, but conceptually, I would like to know, with the new age of single page applications, and tools such as gulp-minify, etc, what is best practice, and let's say I now have 70 minified files, that concatenated 400 .js files, what would be best practice to ship this code (in production)?

NOTE: All of my individual files (about 70) are in the form of IIFEs, so I am not worried about variable name collisions in either the inline script or the concatenated/minified `scripts.min.js` file

Ultimately, I would transform my `index.html` to the following format:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      /* Contents of style.min.css */
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      // Contents of script.min.js
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Body -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Disadvantage is making the actual html page larger. Suggest moving script tag to end of body.

Comment: yes, I have heard that. even with the script tag after the body though, should the script tag point to an external file, or contain the script's code itself?

Comment: Try it both ways and test it with tools like google pageSpeed and see what they think.

Comment: I suggest to read about mod_deflate. It can help reduce js files sizes.

Comment: Haha, Im serving using nginx. But I'll look at compression / mod_deflate analogs for nginx.

Comment: enabling gzip in nginx I believe just takes one line and definitely makes a huge difference in payload size/time to transfer on crap networks.  regarding inline vs external only real benefit to external scripts is if things can be cached in big chunks that normally don't change but other parts do change then the browsers can use their cached copies of the scripts that haven't changed (or use CDN).  If site A uses the same CDN/script as site B then the users browser only needs to load that script when it visits the first of those two.

Comment: One more thing to consider is that script files get cached by browsers also. Will load much quicker when it is cached vs inline